# Code-behind for DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, code-behind, resourcedictionary

I am attempting to use code-behind to support an event handler in a DataTemplate.  The below code works fine when it is the code-behind for a Window, but not for a ResourceDictionary.  The code will not even compile when put in the code-behind for the ResourceDictionary.

I know that Commands is the better option here, but this is largely a test to make sure I can handle events on resources in a ResourceDictionary, if needed.  My goal is to better organize my code, but this is not the straightforward "include" behavior that I thought a separate ResourceDictionary file would provide.

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Window x:Class="Wizbang.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:DevComponents.WpfEditors;assembly=DevComponents.WpfEditors"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:Wizbang"
        xmlns:m ="clr-namespace:Wizbang.Model"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Wizbang.ViewModel"
        xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:Wizbang.View"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        Title="Wizbang" Height="760" Width="1335" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

        <Window.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                 <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MainWindowResources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Window.Resources>
```

In code-behind MainWindow.xaml.cs and MainWindowResources.xaml.cs, the same code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //switch item template
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            //command contains the list item
            ContentControl itm = (ContentControl)btn.CommandParameter;

            itm.SetValue(ContentTemplateProperty, this.FindResource("DetailedTemplate") as DataTemplate);

            //this.UpdateLayout();

        }
```

When I keep the ResourceDictionary inline in MainWindow.xaml, and put the code-behind in MainWindow.xaml.cs, everything works.  When I attempt to use a separate file for ResourceDictionary, the code does not compile. The compiler complains about the last line:

```
itm.SetValue(ContentTemplateProperty, this.FindResource("DetailedTemplate") as DataTemplate);
```

The this.FindResource() is not a valid method, and "ContentTemplateProperty" is not found:

> Error 4   The name
>   'ContentTemplateProperty' does not
>   exist in the current
>   context   C:...\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Wizbang\Wizbang\Resources\MainWindowResources.xaml.cs   36  26  Wizbang
>
> Error 5   'Wizbang.Resources.MainWindowResources'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'FindResource' and no extension method
>   'FindResource' accepting a first
>   argument of type
>   'Wizbang.Resources.MainWindowResources'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:...\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Wizbang\Wizbang\Resources\MainWindowResources.xaml.cs   36  56  Wizbang

If I remove that last line, the code compiles and runs, but the button has no functionality.  I think my issue is mapping that last line's references from the perspective of a ResourceDictionary, but I am not sure why it should be different.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Bill

Comment: What does this have to do with MVVM?  Seeing the [mvvm] and [codebehind] tags together makes my teeth sweat.

Comment: @Will: Even with the excellent suggestion by Erno below for handling RoutedEvents in the ViewModel, there seems to me to still be the potential need to handle some regular Events in the code-behind - even if it is some Event-to-Command sort of code.  My research seems to show the consensus is that, occasionally, handling events in the code-behind is still necessary to avoid complex alternatives. So, the link to MVVM is the ability to handle Events for a DataTemplate contained in a ResourceDictionary, and be able to push the Event info to a Command in a ViewModel, if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the code no longer is in the window class. You have to find it again (or whatever control you want to place the template on).

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(btn);
itm.SetValue(Window.ContentTemplateProperty, parentWindow.FindResource("DetailedTemplate") as DataTemplate);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew I was missing something basic.  Here is the actual code that fixed it: `Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(btn);
            itm.SetValue(Window.ContentTemplateProperty, parentWindow.FindResource("DetailedTemplate") as DataTemplate);`

Comment: Ah yes... I wasn't too sure exactly.I will update the answer. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think that using Commands would be a much cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand the availability of Command mechnism for certain controls, Button being one of them.  And perhaps because Button has commanding available, it is a bad example.  However, as I mention in my description, this scenario is largely a test, in contemplation of the need to support other events - perhaps even with an Event-to-Command mechanism - where commanding is not available or appropriate.

Comment: @Bill: I understand. Please do consider the Behaviors from the Blend SDK in those cases so you can bind an arbitrary event to a command: http://kishordaher.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/routedevent-to-command-action-behavior-blend-3/

Comment: Excellent. Thanks again. That certainly seems to fill the gap between events and commands for a developer trying to keep within the MVVM paradigm.  Would you happen to know if that is a .net 4 only feature, or if it can be used with .net 3.5?

Comment: It is available for .NET 3.5 too. Have a look here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1ae9a30-4928-411d-970b-e682ab179e17&displaylang=en There is a version for Silverlight 4 which requires .NET 4